# Why am i getting Array out of bounds exception for this code?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

```
<@DataProvider>

public Object[][] getdata() {

Object [][] data =new Object [0][1];
data[0][0]="restricteduser";
data[0][1]="123412";

return data;

}
```

We are talking about dataprovider annotation in selenium here.

Comment: Check the size you have given to the array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object [][] data =new Object [1][2];

[1] -> create 1 line

[2] -> with 2 columns

1 line : [ column 1, column 2 ]

data[0][0]="restricteduser"; /* ["restricteduser", null] */

data[0][1]="123412";        /* ["restricteduser", "123412"] */

Comment: what will this do then 
object [] data =new object [2][2]
In my case 3 lines are created with zero index as first line.

Comment: it will do :

line 1 : [ null, null ]
line 2 : [ null, null ]

And for edit (x, y) <=> data [x][y]:
line 1 : [ (0, 0), (0, 1) ]
line 2 : [ (1, 0), (1, 1) ]

Answer (score 0):

```
Object [][] data =new Object [0][1];
```

Here while declaring array we define array size not the index value.  Hence it will be

`Object [][] data =new Object [1][2]; data[0][0]="restricteduser"; data[0][1]="123412";`